# Unreal Engine: Is it possible to animate inside unreal engine?

Tags: animation, unreal-4, skeletal-animation, unreal

I have a skeleton mesh and want to slightly tweak it. Is there a way to do this natively in Unreal Engine instead of resorting to a 3D program?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking if [software X has feature Y](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2383/should-we-consider-does-product-x-have-feature-y-type-questions-as-on-topic).

Comment: This seems like a reasonable question to ask for this site.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Unreal Engine Docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Animation/AnimHowTo/LayerEditing/) you can modify any existing animation sequences as part of "Additive Layer Tracks".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can edit the animation within the animation editor.

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained *how* to edit the animation within the animation editor. What should the user click to access the animation editor in the first place?